# Problems with MVC Controllers + Dependency Injection (Ninject) in medium trust

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, medium-trust

I want to use dependency injection in an medium trust environment. To that aim I picked [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) as Iv been told its light weight. How do I set-up injection into the controllers?

When I tried to create a custom controller factory:

```
 public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly IKernel _kernel;
        public NinjectControllerFactory(params IModule[] modules)
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);
        }

        public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            IController controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
            _kernel.Inject(controller);
            return controller;
        }
    }
```

But I'm encountering this error:

> ```
>  System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   Message="An error occurred while creating a controller of type 'xxx'.
> ```
>
> If the controller doesn't have a
>   controller factory, ensure that it has
>   a parameterless public constructor."

Any idea how to get Ninject or any other IoC framework working under medium trust (meaning no use of reflection)

Answer (score 2):

To run Ninject 1.x in medium trust, you must set the `UseReflectionBasedInjection` option to `true`. Ninject 2.0 does not suffer from this limitation.

Reflection is actually not a protected operation in medium trust, but lightweight code generation (which Ninject uses by default for injection) is -- at least before .NET 3.5 SP1.

Once you switch to reflection-based injection, your code should work as intended. I'd also encourage you to look at Ninject.Framework.Mvc (for Ninject 1.x) or Ninject.Web.Mvc (for Ninject 2.0). These extensions handle the heavy-lifting for you.

Comment: I was using ninject 2. Ninject.Web.Mvc is not medium trust firendly

Answer (score 2):

I never managed to resolved this issue in the end, I switched to [Unity](http://codeplex.com/unity) - works in  medium trust without any hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set this option when creating your container:

```
UseReflectionBasedInjection = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good tip(but did you mean set it to false?), I changed my constructor so that its like this:

```
public NinjectControllerFactory(params IModule[] modules)
        {
            _kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);
            _kernel.Options.UseReflectionBasedInjection = false;
        }
```

**This gets the same exception though.**

I also tried overriding GetControllerInstance like this too

```
  protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
    {
        return _kernel.Get(controllerType) as IController;
    }
```

But this throws an security exception because it uses reflection.